# SQL script stuck with status: runnable and wait: preemptive_os_reportevent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

An Index Defrag was executed and was later on terminated. It impacted 2 other processes to long run. One process cancelled by itself and the other was terminated. While re-running I was checking the status from sys.dm_exec_requests and notice that on the last part of the query which will insert the data into a table, it is changing status from running to runnable: preemptive_os_reportevent, etc.. Later on, the job once again cancelled by itself.

I want to learn why is the script changing status like that? Is that expected? And if something else is causing it to long run, what else should I check?

Note: I was also checking other active scripts at the time it was running and none was using the same target table.

Comment: It seems this question could be more easily answered at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I raised this same question in dba.stackexchange.com but still waiting if someone else can answer this one. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved yesterday. Apparently, the syslogs was full and is prohibiting the script to write logs therefore it is stuck and can't complete. Feel free to add inputs if you have some.